# how can i help my parants from getting a divorce

Tags: parents, divorce

im a young tenager and my parents are constantly arguing.

my mum has recantly taken off her rings and was joking around about splitting up, but i think they might actually.

i dont know what to do and im scared they might split up since it would effect my mental health (which is terrible) and might push me past the braking piont.

can somone help, please can you give me some advice.

Comment: First of all, you should probably have an honest conversation with them and tell them how you are feeling. Also, you say you are afraid it might push you past your breaking point - if you are already at the end of your rope then maybe look into going to a therapist, because whether they split up or not that's not a good mental state to be in. Plus, realize that their decisions are out of your control. All you can control is how you react to the situation at hand.

Comment: Additionally, you need a rock - something to anchor you. Whether its G-d (the best option I would say), a really close friend, a therapist - you need an anchoring point. There was a big rabbi who put it very well - during the holocaust he was in a concentration camp for years, and his wife, 11 kids, and much of his followers were all wiped out by the Nazis. And after that he said something along the lines of 'the Nazis took my family, my community, my dignity - but G-d they could never take from me'.